# JSDoc - mark some code to not be parsed but retain documentation?

Tags: jsdoc

I'm trying to document a Javascript file with JSDoc(3) like so:

```
/** 1 if gnome-bluetooth is available, 0 otherwise                              
 * @type {boolean}                                                              
 * @const                                                                                                                                           
 */                                                                             
const HAVE_BLUETOOTH = @HAVE_BLUETOOTH@;
```

Now the file (called `config.js.in`) is not on its own valid Javascript; the file gets run through a Makefile which substitutes an appropriate value for `@HAVE_BLUETOOTH@`.

When I try to run JSdoc on this, it (understandably) balks because of the syntax error in the file.

**Is there some way to tell JSDoc to ignore *all* code in this file but simply take into account the annotations**? (I might have to add `@name` tags to each doclet to completely separate the documentation from the code; that's fine).

Something like:

```
/** 1 if gnome-bluetooth is available, 0 otherwise                              
 * @name HAVE_BLUETOOTH
 * @type {boolean}                                                              
 * @const                                                                 
 */                    
/** @ignore */  // somehow ignore from here onwards
const HAVE_BLUETOOTH = @HAVE_BLUETOOTH@; 
/** !@ignore */ // somehow don't ignore from here onwards (although I'd be happy
                // to ignore the entire file)
```

I'd prefer not to modify the code part of the file, if possible (I'm adding documentation to an existing project). For example, I could probably get around it with

```
const HAVE_BLUETOOTH = parseInt('@HAVE_BLUETOOTH@', 10);
```

which would make the file have valid JS syntax again so that the parser doesn't complain, but this also means I'm modifying the code of the original file which I want to avoid (I prefer to *just* add documentation).

cheers

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Can't you change the pipeline so that jsdoc is run on an intermediate, compiled version before you minify, etc everything? If not, a less intrusive code hack is const HAVE_BLUETOOTH = +'@HAVE_BLUETHOOTH@';

Answer (score 0):

My case is similar because I use JSDoc to comment my `.less` and `.css` file. When I running JSDoc on set of file, I have the same issue.

So, I resolve my problem (with JSDoc 3.3.3) with the `commentsOnly` JSDoc plugin

- https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/blob/master/plugins/commentsOnly.js

I have create this `config.json`:

```
{
    "source": {
        "includePattern": ".+\\.(css|less)?$"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "plugin/commentsOnly"
    ]
}
```

with the `commentsOnly.js` file into a `plugin/` directory (consider `plugin/` and `config.json` are in same folder) and in this folder I execute the following CLI command:

```
jsdoc -c ./config.json ./assets/stylesheets/common.less
```

And it's work ! There are no reason this do not work with your files.

Hope I help you ;)