# Utilizing docstrings

Tags: javascript, node.js, docstring

It's a newbie question, but I didn't manage to google anything reasonably concise yet enlightening on the subject. I've got `Sublime Text` editor and an excellent plugin `DocBlockr` https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs , which makes proper commenting a piece of cake. What am I supposed to do after I'm through with the comments? At a very minimum, I'd like to be able to invoke annotations in REPL. What else documentation wise is available? I want something lightweight and easy, for medium scripts.

EDIT:

```
var helper = exports.helper = (function() {

...

  /**
   * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
   * @param  {String} name  Space Delimited sequence of names.
   * @param  {String} sep   A period separating the initials.
   * @param  {String} trail A period ending the initials.
   * @param  {String} hyph  A hypen separating double names.
   * @return {String}       Properly formatted initials.
   */
  function makeInits(name, sep, trail, hyph) {
    function splitBySpace(nm) {
      return nm.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function(x) {return x[0]}).join(sep).toUpperCase();
    }
    return name.split(hyph).map(splitBySpace).join(hyph) + trail;
  }
  /**
   * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
   * @param  {String} name Space delimited sequence of names.
   * @return {String}      Properly formatted initials.
   */
  function makeInitials(name) {
    return makeInits(name, '.', '.', '-');
  }

...

})();
```

With `$ jsdoc src.js` no errors, but only dummy header is generated.

Answer (score 53):

When you write this

```
function bar (foo) {
    return foo + foo;
}
```

If you place your cursor in the line just above `function` and you write `/**` when you push « Enter » you'll be obtain this:

```
/**
 * [bar description]
 * @param  {[type]} foo [description]
 * @return {[type]}     [description]
 */
function bar (foo) {
    return foo + foo;
}
```

There are a lot of similary shortcurt.

For example, if you place your cursor after `@param  {[type]} foo [description]`, push « Enter » will create a new a `*`  line, and write `@` will propose you (in the intellisense) all JSDoc comments and the validation create a full line.

When your file is correctly documented, just use the `jsdoc` CLI to create your documentation.

Documentation: https://jsdoc.app/

EDIT: I just realize the response to your question is in your https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs link so maybe you want know how generate the documentation so...

Install Node.js and use CLI command

```
npm install jsdoc -g
```

Then, supposed file name you want document is `foo.js`, run the following command:

```
jsdoc foo.js
```

This will create a documentation into `out` directory.

All CLI documentation to generate doc is here : https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html

Comment: I did try this. The 'site' generated silently. The page is empty under the header. In my JavaScript source there are two functions commented experimentally. Those functions are inside 'modules', i.e. local in anonymous functions representing the body of the module.

Comment: It's probably because you not use the `@memberOf` property to reference that function under the module so `@memberof` module:MyModuleName~ could do the job. Edit your post to provide the code that not properly appear in your documentation if you want.

Comment: Something like that, hopefully. I tried `@memberOf module:helper~`, to no avail. In fact, my module is anonymous, so I am not really surprised.

Comment: "Documentation: http://usejsdoc.org/" is a deadlink. I assume it is now https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html

Answer (score 9):

**On Global**

To allow JSDoc Template to generate your documentation, you have to add the `@function` attribute with the name of your function. Your two functions will appear in Global part of the template.

```
jsdoc your-exemple.js
```

But, because of your function are scoped in an anonymous function (but no module for moment), you do add the @private function to inform that function are not really global but just accessible in its scope. But, because by default JSDoc Generator Template ignore privates functions, add the `--private` options.

```
jsdoc your-exemple.js --private
```

So your code look like this.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // ...

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInits
     * @private
     * @param  {String} name  Space Delimited sequence of names.
     * @param  {String} sep   A period separating the initials.
     * @param  {String} trail A period ending the initials.
     * @param  {String} hyph  A hypen separating double names.
     * @return {String}       Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInits(name, sep, trail, hyph) {
        function splitBySpace(nm) {
            return nm.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function (x) { return x[0]; }).join(sep).toUpperCase();
        }
        return name.split(hyph).map(splitBySpace).join(hyph) + trail;
    }

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInitials
     * @private
     * @param  {String} name Space delimited sequence of names.
     * @return {String}      Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInitials(name) {
        return makeInits(name, '.', '.', '-');
    }

    // ...

}());
```

**Into Class**

If you expose the content of anonymous closure to a variable `var Helper`, it's possibly a Class. So your code will not be a part of Global content but a part of Class with `@class` following by class name. And because you will provide your function towards the class module, you have no need to declare function as private.

But you do explain your previous function are part of the class so you have to use `@memberOf` with the full path to property.

- Ending by `.` if it's a static member (exposed via return).
- Ending by `#` if it's a method instanciable (exposed via this).
- Ending by `~` if it's a private function not exposed at all (and `@private`).

So

```
/**
 * Helper Class
 * @Class Helper
 */
var Helper = (function () {
    "use strict";

    // ...

    /**
     * Split by Space
     * @function privateExemple
     * @private
     * @memberOf Helper~
     * @return {String}     ...
     */
    function privateExemple() {
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInits
     * @memberOf Helper.
     * @param  {String} name  Space Delimited sequence of names.
     * @param  {String} sep   A period separating the initials.
     * @param  {String} trail A period ending the initials.
     * @param  {String} hyph  A hypen separating double names.
     * @return {String}       Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInits(name, sep, trail, hyph) {
        function splitBySpace(nm, sep) {
            return nm.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function (x) { return x[0]; }).join(sep).toUpperCase();
        }
        return name.split(hyph).map(splitBySpace).join(hyph) + trail;
    }

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @method makeInitials
     * @memberOf Helper#
     * @param  {String} name Space delimited sequence of names.
     * @return {String}      Properly formatted initials.
     */
    this.makeInitials = function makeInitials(name) {
        return makeInits(name, '.', '.', '-');
    }

    // ...

    return {
        makeInits: makeInits
    };
}());
```

**Into Molule**

But, in your case you use the `exports` so that mean your file is a module. So you have to describe this with `@module` and the name. So, all what you have previously comment will be not a part of Global but now a part of your Module. And because you will provide your function behind the Helper module, you have no need to declare function as private.

```
/**
 * Helper Module
 * @module Helper
 */
exports.helper = (function () {
    "use strict";

    // ...

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInits
     * @memberOf module:helper.
     * @param  {String} name  Space Delimited sequence of names.
     * @param  {String} sep   A period separating the initials.
     * @param  {String} trail A period ending the initials.
     * @param  {String} hyph  A hypen separating double names.
     * @return {String}       Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInits(name, sep, trail, hyph) {
        function splitBySpace(nm) {
            return nm.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function (x) { return x[0]; }).join(sep).toUpperCase();
        }
        return name.split(hyph).map(splitBySpace).join(hyph) + trail;
    }

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInitials
     * @private
     * @memberOf module:helper~
     * @param  {String} name Space delimited sequence of names.
     * @return {String}      Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInitials(name) {
        return makeInits(name, '.', '.', '-');
    }

    // ...

    return {
        makeInitials: makeInitials
    };
}());
```

**Module and Class**

But, because you expose via `var Helper` as a Class and via `exports` as a Module you could document in both way.

```
/**
 * Helper Class
 * @class Helper
 * @memberOf module:helper~
 * @see  {@link module:helper|Module}
 */
var Helper = (function () {
    "use strict";

    // ...

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInits
     * @memberOf module:helper.
     * @param  {String} name  Space Delimited sequence of names.
     * @param  {String} sep   A period separating the initials.
     * @param  {String} trail A period ending the initials.
     * @param  {String} hyph  A hypen separating double names.
     * @return {String}       Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInits(name, sep, trail, hyph) {
        function splitBySpace(nm) {
            return nm.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function (x) { return x[0]; }).join(sep).toUpperCase();
        }
        return name.split(hyph).map(splitBySpace).join(hyph) + trail;
    }

    /**
     * Reduces a sequence of names to initials.
     * @function makeInitials
     * @private
     * @memberOf module:helper~
     * @param  {String} name Space delimited sequence of names.
     * @return {String}      Properly formatted initials.
     */
    function makeInitials(name) {
        return makeInits(name, '.', '.', '-');
    }

    // ...

    return {
        makeInitials: makeInitials
    };
}());

/**
 * helper Module
 * @module helper
 */
exports.helper = Helper;
```

**Namespace or Class ?**

The difference between a Class and a Namespace is just the Class expose some objects/functions via `this` and is instanciable. If nothing is attached to this, you have possibly a namespace so just replace @class by @namespace and that code will be placed into appropriate Namespace section.

You also check if your Class is not an Mixin (just used accross over Class but never directly) or an Interface (defined but not implement) if it an @extend of other class.

etc.

See the doc: http://usejsdoc.org/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Haeresis! Nothing works in my crooked hands, unfortunately. Class is beside the point (not instantiable), it's either module, or namespace. Can there be more than one module per file, by the way? Or more than one namespace? As a last resort, I venture to give you the reference to the entire project (it's just an educational sketch) https://github.com/Tyrn/js-procr . My intention (reasonable encapsulation) should be self-evident.

Comment: So, I have download your GitHub project.
I open a CLI command into root and I run the following command `jsdoc procr/pcn.js` and I have the following error:

`ERROR. Unable to parse xxx Line 291: Illegal return statement` so

To the 291 line there are a `return` in the Global scope. That is not allowed. Remove this line and re-run command. Will be work this time.

To generate doc without care about error into files, follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890682/jsdoc-mark-some-code-to-not-be-parsed-but-retain-documentation/34092004#34092004

Comment: (1) I've never seen this error. (2) The if-return statement is necessary: the script isn't supposed to run while imported for unit testing. It's just like Python's idiom `if __name__ == '__main__': run()`. I'll have to take some time to try and digest your suggestions. Thanks again!

Comment: Just do that `if(require.main === module) { main.copyAlbum(); }` not solve your problem ? If you test `var require = {},
    module = {};
if (require.main !== module) {
    return null;
}` in http://www.jslint.com/ you will obtain `Unexpected 'return' at top level.`
Else, in my previous link you have the solution without modify your code if you want.

Comment: Got rid of the return statement. It looks better, but certain screenshot lead me to expect more :) .

Comment: Version 0.1 published :) Maybe sane, yet doesn't look like much. Options?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by « screenshot lead me to expect more » ? Would you say the `if (require.main === module)` is not so clean ? You have the factory pattern if you want a more elegant solution for not use the return statement https://github.com/thybzi/styledoc/blob/master/styledoc.js but if you want more details on this point, you have to post another question.

Answer (score 0):

In your page: https://github.com/Tyrn/js-procr/blob/master/procr/pcn.js

You have the following line:

```
if (require.main !== module) return false;
```

That produce the following error: `ERROR. Unable to parse xxx Line 291: Illegal return statement`.

It's because no `return` is allowed in global scope so use this insteed:

```
if (require.main === module) {
    main.copyAlbum();
}
```

And all your documentation will be produced like a charm.

Actually, I don't know why your jsdoc command produce no errors in your environnent.